Debugging Angular app in VSCode is not working - launching blank window
Since last few weeks, my edge/chrome debugger stopped working when I press F5 to run and debug, after running "npm start" command for my Angular application. A blank window with url "about:blank" shows up instead of "localhost:4200"

My launch.json contains following contents:
{
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-msedge", // "type": "msedge" also doesn't work
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Edge",
        "url": "https://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app",
        //"preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
        "url": "https://localhost:4200/"
    },
    {
        "name": "ng test",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: test",
        "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html"
    }
] }

I have tried to follow below articles, but no luck so far:
Debugging Angular app in VSCode is not working AGAIN
Debugging of Angular app created with "dotnet new angular" is not working in VSCode

That https looks suspicious. Try with http. Also check your web browser console for errors.

I tried with http, but no luck. Also, I don't see anything in console and source, both are empty.

Try just runing ng serve then manually going to localhost:4200 on http.

That works with both http and https! However, the debugger doesn't stop in vs code. I have to open developer tools and put breakpoint there. My purpose of this ticket was to run/launch debugger using vs code

I understand, sorry I can't help, I don't use debugger in vscode, I always write debugger; statement to make it stop in browser. Good luck
